# JavaScript Blackjack Game Coding Questions

Tags: javascript, blackjack

An assignment in my class is requiring me to write a VERY basic javascript blackjack game. The dealer's hand is automatically generated at a value between 17 and 21, so only the player has to make a decision for what to do.

I've created a random generator for the dealer's hand as well as a random generator that results in values 1-13 (Ace-King) as per the requirements of the assignment. But the values 11 and 12 and 13 correspond to face cards (Jack/Queen/King) which all have an equal value of 10 obviously. But how do I reassign the values 11-13 to have a value of 10?

I'm also having trouble figuring out how to write the decision structure for the player. Basically looking for something that will give me the following output:

Would you like a card? (player inputs answer)
You received a 7. Would you like another card? (player inputs answer)
You received a King. Your total is 17. Would you like another card?

etc...

I'm not looking for anyone to write the complete code for me, just looking for a start because I'm having difficulty even figuring out where to begin with all this. The design structure of the assignment is VERY open, however it's supposed to remain at the most simple/basic level possible for JavaScript. Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: i'd use buttons and a text field for the decision structure. BlackJack uses 'twist' for another card and 'stick' if you don't want another card.

Comment: edit your post to show your code if you want specific help

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How do I reassign the values 11-13 to have a value of 10?

1. Use an if statement to check if the number is between 11-13 and assign it to 10

> 2. Basically looking for something that will give me the following output.

2. You structure looks like a while loop would work. (while the player wants a card, keep dealing them to him/her and adding it to their total. If they bust, end the while loop; if the choose not to take another card exit the while loop and compare who had a better score. The dealer or the player.

Good luck with your assignment.

Edit:

```
 if(playerCard >=10){
    playerCard = 10;
 }
```

You don't need an else here, because if playerCard < 10 you don't want to change it anyway.

Comment: Something like this?

    if (playerCard >=10)
       {
        playerCard = 10
       }
    else.....?

Comment: that looks fine to me as long as playerCard is defined and is an integer

Comment: Edit my original post? For some reason can't get the four space code to work in replies.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the card values, I would suggest storing the cards as an *object* to hold their value and their type.

```
var cards = [ { name: 'Ace', value: 1 },
              { name: '2', value: 2 },
              { name: '3', value: 3 },
              { name: '4', value: 4 },
              { name: '5', value: 5 },
              { name: '6', value: 6 },
              { name: '7', value: 7 },
              { name: '8', value: 8 },
              { name: '9', value: 9 },
              { name: '10', value: 10 },
              { name: 'Jack', value: 11 },
              { name: 'Queen', value: 12 },
              { name: 'King', value: 13 }
            ];
```

You can then access a *Jack* in the following way

```
var name = card[9].name;
var value = card[9].value;
```

I would suggest including another field called alt value for the case of an *ace* being 1 or 11.

eg.

```
{ name: 'Ace', value: 1, altValue = 11 }
```

---

**Additional Logic**
If the game is based around a single deck of cards,I would map every single possible card and store it in the card array complete with suit.

eg.

```
var cards = [ { name: 'Ace', value: 1 altValue: 11, suit: 'Hearts' },
              { name: '2', value: 2, suit: 'Hearts' }...
```

Then I would remove a card from the game when it is delt to someone by removing it from the cards array.